# Computing the un-weighted length of a weighted shortest path

Tags: r, algorithm, igraph

I have started investigating whether `igraph` would be a more efficient method for calculating the length of a least cost path. Using the package `gdistance` it is straightforward to supply a cost surface and generated least cost paths between two (or many) points. The function `costDistance` returns the actual length of the paths as the sum of all the segments lengths (i.e. not the cumulative COST of the least cost path).

My question is whether there is way to do this in `igraph` so that i can compare computation time. Using `get.shortest.paths`, i can obtain the length of the shortest path between vertices, but, when edge weights  are provided, the path path length is reported as the weighted path length.

In short: i would like to find shortest paths on a weighted network but have the lengths reported in terms of edge length, not weighted edge length.

Note: I can see how this is possible by looping through each shortest path and then writing some extra code to just add up the unweighted edge lengths, but i fear this will cancel out my original need for increased efficiency of pairwise distance calculations over massive networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `get.shortest.paths`, there is a `weights` argument! If you read `?get.shortest.paths` you will find that `weights` is

> Possibly a numeric vector giving edge weights. If this is NULL and the graph has a weight edge attribute, then the attribute is used. If this is NA then no weights are used (even if the graph has a weight attribute).

So you should set `weights = NA`. See below for an example:

```
require(igraph)
# make a reproducible example
el <- matrix(nc=3, byrow=TRUE,
             c(1,2,.5, 1,3,2, 2,3,.5) )
g2 <- add.edes(graph.empty(3), t(el[,1:2]), weight=el[,3])
# calculate weighted shortest distance between vertice 1 and 3
get.shortest.paths(g2, 1, 3)
# calculate unweighted shortest distance between vertice 1 and 3
get.shortest.paths(g2, 1, 3, weights=NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I completely understand what "edge length" and "weighted edge length" means in your post (I guess that "edge length" is simply "the number of edges along the path" and "weighted edge length" is "the total weights of the edges along the path"), but if I'm right, your problem simply boils down to "finding shortest paths where edges are weighted by one particular criteria and then returning a length for each path which is the sum of some *other* properties of the edges involved".

If this is the case, you can pass the `output="epath"` parameter to `get.shortest.paths`; in this case, igraph will report the IDs of the edges along the weighted shortest path between two nodes. You can then use these IDs as indices into a vector containing the values of that *other* property that you wish to use when the lengths are calculated. E.g.:

```
> g <- grg.game(100, 0.2)
> E(g)$weight <- runif(ecount(g), min=1, max=20)
> E(g)$length <- runif(ecount(g), min=1, max=20)
> path <- unlist(get.shortest.paths(g, from=1, to=100, output="epath")[[1]]$epath)
> sum(E(g)$length[path])
```

This will give you the sum of the `length` attributes of the edges involved in the shortest path between nodes 1 and 100, while the shortest paths are calculated using the `weight` attribute (which is the default for `get.shortest.paths`, but you can also override it with the `weights=...` argument).

If you are simply interested in the *number* of edges on the path, you can either use a constant 1 for the lengths, or simply call `length(path)` in the last line.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do. I am attempting to use igraph to calculate geographic distances. So, the value of an edge is the Euclidean distance between vertices, the 'weighted edge length' is Euclidean distance multiplied by a cost value  associated with moving between two nodes (the _other_ property as you rightly pointed out). Your solution will definitely work. I will test if out and see how it does for calculating pairwise distances across the entire network.